# Cannot align elements when using 'position:fixed'

Tags: html, css, css-position

I can't seem to find a way to display elements inline when the position is `fixed`. Every other position works except for fixed positioning. Any suggestions?

I currently have five equal rectangles that are supposed to line up next to each and fill an entire view port. However, when I use fixed positioning, they all converge into one single spot.

My code is below:

### HTML

```html
<span class="reveal"></span><span class="reveal1"></span><span class="reveal2"></span><span class="reveal3"></span><span class="reveal4"></span>
```

### CSS

```css
.reveal {
     width: 20%;
     height: 100vh;
     position: fixed;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .reveal1 {
     width: 20%;
     height: 100vh;
     position: fixed;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .reveal2 {
     width: 20%;
     height: 100vh;
     position: fixed;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .reveal3 {
     width: 20%;
     height: 100vh;
     position: fixed;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .reveal4 {
     width: 20%;
     height: 100vh;
     position: fixed;
     display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<header></header>
  <body>
    <span class ="reveal" > a</span > 
    <span class ="reveal1" > b</span > 
    <span class ="reveal2" > c</span > 
    <span class ="reveal3" > d</span > 
    <span class ="reveal4" > e</span >
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please update what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated it, thanks.

Comment: try and use float attribute. float:left would work i guess!

Comment: I have 5 total elements, using `float: left` would result in the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have added `position:fixed` to all elements and when an element has a `position of fixed` it by default takes `left and top as 0` i.e. `aligning` of element, so you could try somethings as below or `wrap` your code by a `parent div` and set it's `position` as `fixed` instead of all elements.

> position:fixed - Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position
>   it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't
>   move it when scrolled.

```css
.reveal {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#33f;
}

.reveal1 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#f2f;
    left:20%;
}

.reveal2 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#22f;
    left:40%;
}

.reveal3 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#f22;
    left:60%;
}

.reveal4 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#f2f;
    left:80%;
    }
```

```html
<span class="reveal"></span><span class="reveal1"></span><span class="reveal2"></span><span class="reveal3"></span><span class="reveal4"></span>
```

Or by wrapping it into parent div as below,

```css
#box{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.reveal {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#33f;
}

.reveal1 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#f2f;
}

.reveal2 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#22f;
}

.reveal3 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#f22;
}

.reveal4 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    background:#f2f;
    }
```

```html
<div id="box">
<span class="reveal"></span><span class="reveal1"></span><span class="reveal2"></span><span class="reveal3"></span><span class="reveal4"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Welcome @LordGoderick :-) explanation is needed so that in future your question might be useful for someone else.

Comment: I think I prefer the wrapping method, it feels more structured, and yes I will explain better.

Comment: @LordGoderick That's true, easy to understand. Do accept if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using fixed positions, you have to provide left positions to each of the blocks. Please find updated code below, I added some background colors to help distinguish. CSS below :

```
.reveal {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    left: 0;
}

.reveal1 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    left: 20%;
}

.reveal2 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    left: 40%;

}

.reveal3 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background: orange;
    left: 60%;

}

.reveal4 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    left: 80%;
}
```

Please let me know if this works. On a side, why are you fixed positioning in the first place?

Hope this helps.

Comment: @LordGoderick Thanks a lot :) Please accept the answer as the selected answer. Thanks!

Comment: I gave the accepted answer to @frnt as it went into greater detail with examples despite coming later but your answer was also very good. I'm using fixed positioning as I am animating it as a preloader.

Comment: No worries! Sounds fair :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap everything in a new div and make that position fixed.

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

span {
  background: red;
}

.reveal {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.reveal1 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.reveal2 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.reveal3 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.reveal4 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <span class="reveal"></span><span class="reveal1"></span><span class="reveal2"></span><span class="reveal3"></span><span class="reveal4"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not display: block, it's position: fixed makes div stretch relatively to browser window,

Just add another class. and split the contradiction in CSS between them

```
<div class="one"><span class="reveal"></span></div>
<style>
.reveal {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
}

.one
{
position: fixed;
}
</style>
```

Try the above code